# Why is the column width of tables in wordpress behaving this way?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress site, with which I don't have much experience. I'm using a plugin called wp-table-reloaded. I'd like to be able to edit the column width of the columns on this page: http://zangkoor.netii.net/het-koor/het-bestuur-2/. I know that the cells have classes `.column-1`and so on, so I know I could edit the styles for these, but what I don't get, is why the first column is much wider than the second. I've been looking at the styles using the chrome inspector, but I can't find what's causing it. Also, I'm making the site for my dad, so if I could give him an easier way to edit column widths, without fiddling with css, that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is smart enough and has been made for progressive enhancements. If you start putting in the content for third Column as much as you want, you would see the first 2 columns shrink in size. The ambiguity that you see right now is because you have empty cells in the third column. Once you start filling content in those cells, everything should fall in place. That said you can hide the third column entirely by giving the CSS declaration display:none; for column-3 like

```
.column-3{display:none;}
```

Comment: Thx. I'll go hide that column. It'll contain images of choir members.

Comment: Now the third column has content, but the first is still larger than the second one, and now the image in the third column has a huge ammount of margin/padding/whatever, to the left. I'm trying to find out what's causing it. I'm used to hand-coding pages, so I'm still discovering what parts are added by the cms and its plugins.

Comment: can you try adding more content to 2nd and 3rd columns and see what happens? first col will always be slightly wider than the other two.